# Django model foreign key from existing table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration

In my django project I use [django-registration](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration) reusable app. I install this app and run syncdb. It's create for me table 'registration_registrationprofiles' in my database. Then I create a new app and write this code in my models.py:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('registration_registrationprofiles')
```

And run manage.py makemigrations and it throw me exception:

```
ERRORS:
comments.Comments.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation 
with model 'registration_registrationprofiles', which is either
not installed, or is abstract.
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Migration has `dependencies` set at the latest migration of the django-registration app?

Comment: `ForeignKey` accepts either a model, a model name, or a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
```

and then:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(RegistrationProfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrations can have dependencies declared. Usually, makemigrations does a good job with that, but it looks like it missed it this time. I suggest you locate the migration file it created (in `your_app/migrations`) and check its `dependencies`. It should look like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [("registration", "0042_some_migration")]

    # operations...
```

The key here it the `dependencies` array should reference the registration app, and the latest migration (or at least the latest you depend on).

Then `manage.py makemigrations` will detect the dependency and run migrations in the correct order.